# How to determine the following matrix decomposition?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ and $V$ be matrices, with $V$ being semidefinite positive.
We would like to decompose $AVA^{T}$ as a product of three matrices
such that

\begin{equation}
AVA^{T}=\begin{bmatrix}I & A\end{bmatrix}.X.\begin{bmatrix}I\\
A^{T}
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
with $I$ being the identity matrix. So we would like to determine
$X$. The matrix $X$ has to respect the following constraint: $X$
is symmetric, invertible and depends only on $V$. One can think for
example that 
\begin{equation}
X=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\
0 & V
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
but it is not possible since $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\
0 & V
\end{bmatrix}$  is not invertible. Can anyone
help me determining $X$ please? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you will be luckier with antidiagonal $J$ and $[J,A] X [-J,A]^T$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think I will modify the problem in order to use this decomposition, which is simpler to determine.

Comment: Please don't modify a question that has already got answers, unless you do it with a very visible edit and keep the original formulation.

Comment: Of course, I will not modify it on stackexchange. I was talking about modifying in my own work's problem statement. Thanks

Comment: $[0,A]X[0,A]^T$ would also work regardless of entries of X except for V in position 2,2, so then you have the freedom to fill X up with whatever you want at block positiosn (1,1), (1,2) (2,1)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that there are other constraints that impose to have a decomposition of the form $[I A]X[I A]^{T}$

Comment: But I can have linear terms of another matrix except A in X

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to write down $ X $ (using its symmetry) in $ \begin{bmatrix} X_1 & X_2 \\ X_2 & X_3 \end{bmatrix} $ (like in your example) and you will obtain (from the identity that you would have):
$$ A (V-X_3) A^T = X_1 + 2 sym(AX_2) $$
(with $ sym(K) $ the symmetric part of $ K $).
It is not clear for me if there always exists a solution of your problem. Maybe you can try to look for a counterexample or to do a particular assignment to some $ X_i, \, (i=1,2,3) $, and find the other matrices that form $ X $.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose $X=\begin{bmatrix} X_{11}& X_{12} \\ X_{21} &X_{22}\end{bmatrix}$ you get (by multiplying your rhs) to 
$$
X_{11}+AX_{21}+(AX_{12})^T + AX_{22}A^T = AVA^T
$$
By choosing $X_{11}=0$ and a skew-symmetric $X_{21}$ and $X_{22}=V$ you will get a valid matrix $X$ to fulfill your equation. I'm not sure about the regularity though.

Comment: Thank you Laray. You are right but If $X_{21}$ is a skew-symmetric matrix, the big matrix X is not symmetric anymore.

Comment: This would add also another constraint, which is that $A$ and $X_{21}$ must commute: it will be difficult to solve, I think.